# Right clicking on windows logo in Server 2012 r2 brings nothing up and empty Tools menu in Server Manager

Tags: user-interface, windows-server-2012-r2

There is something wrong with the user interface on my server, when I right click on the windows logo (in the lower left corner) then nothing happens, no menu appears with the usual options. Also in Server Manager, then the Tools menu (upper right corner) is empty, the Manage, View and Help menus work. The Tools menu had some items in it but at one time they all disappeared, so the roles and services are all installed, they just don't show up in the Tools menu.

This happens for new users also, so it is not just one user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Running sfc /scannow from command line with Administrative privelages fixed this issue.